# In SQL, are tuple variables mainly used to save typing-effort?

Tags: sql, tuples

In a statement like this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, T.LOAN_NUMBER, S.AMOUNT
FROM BORROWER AS T, LOAN AS S
WHERE T.LOAN_NUMBER = S.LOAN_NUMBER
```

So the tuple variables here are T and S?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are useful for saving typing, but there are other reasons to use them:

- If you join a table to itself you must give it two different names otherwise referencing the table would be ambiguous.
- It can be useful to give names to derived tables, and in some database systems it is *required*... even if you never refer to the name.

Regarding the name, "tuple" comes from the idea that a row is a [tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) of values, e.g. `(1, 'Fred', 1400)`. However I *don't* know why it is called a variable, because it cannot be modified afterwards. I don't think this is a particularly common term to describe this feature. The [SQL Standards](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) refer to them as "correlation names". Looking at the major databases, all of them use another term instead:

- In the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) they are refered to as *aliases* rather than *tuple variables*.
- The [Oracle manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2126863) describes them as *table aliases* or *correlation names*.
- The [SQL Server manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) also uses the term *table alias*.

Comment: That's very interesting that you can join a table with itself, I think I can see now where that would be needed. Thank You So Much!

Comment: "However I *don't* know why it is called a variable, because it cannot be modified afterwards" -- note in a relational language we could expect `BORROWER` and `LOAN` to be 'relation variables' or 'relvars' for short. The idea is that their contents may vary over time due to modifications to the database. Note a database is also a variable, albeit a complex one! Whether one accepts that the SQL equivalent of a relvar is a table is another matter ;)